# ASP.NET MVC better place for composing viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I have typical MVC solution with next projects of models:

- Solution.Model
- Solution.ViewModel

For example **ProductController**

```
public ActionResult Index(int productId)
{
   Model.Product product = context.Products.GetById(productId);
   ViewModel.ProductViewModel productVM = new ProductViewModel();
   productVM.Title =  product.Title;
   ...
}
```

Obvious that Controllers not a suit place for composing view models
I see couple if options for it:

- constructor of viewModel
- composing in controllers by means of automaper
- separate acceble

What is best practice?

Comment: Might I point you to the Code Review site of Stack Overflow: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: did you by chance mean "automapper" when you said "aftomaper"?

Comment: I'd collapse all your statements down to a single linq call that outputs the the viewmodel.  like context.Products.Where(p => p.Id == productId).Select(p => new ProductViewModel { Title = p.Title, .... }).ToList();  would that make using the controller more suitable?

Comment: Just use AutoMapper if the problem is mapping your entities to viewmodel's

Comment: automaper not bad but it has some drawbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Business Model should not depend on ViewModel (i.e. fill ViewModel in Business logic layer)
2. ViewModel should not depend on Business Model (i.e. fill ViewModel from Model in constructor of ViewModel)

Model and ViewModel should be independent from each other!

So, controller is that "layer" to "connect" ViewModel and Model. I recommend to use automapper for this purpose